# Adding classes to javascript onhover code

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Currently I, in my page, have an external script, that causes the text within the div "contact"   to change color depending on which "item" element is hovered. Now I wish that it is not only the "contact div, that changes color but also the menu div  and the curriculum div , as well as any other div, that I might feel like adding later on. I have tried to change my current javascript in order to do so, by adding another let variable and including that in the script. However Nothing has worked up untill this point. I am currently studying on my javascript, to be able to make these changes. But maybe someone could tell how this is done in the cleanest way possible?

```js
let $contact = $('#contact');


$('.item').hover(function() {
  let $target = $($(this).data('target')).toggleClass('hide_default');
  $('#contact').css('color', $target.css('color'));
});
```

```css
/* Body */

* {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Header */

#main {
  overflow: auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}


/* Contacts */

#contact {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#About {
  margin: 50px;
}

#container_1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 500px;
}

#container_1>* {
  height: 10vh;
  margin: 12rem;
  position: center;
}

.hide_default {
  display: none;
}


/* Slider */

.slider {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-size: 45px;
  float: left;
  height: 260px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10001;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.nav-bar-column-1 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 160px;
  margin-left: 160px;
}

.nav-bar-column-2 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  width: 700px;
  margin-right: 160px;
  margin-left: 160px;
}

.nav-bar-column-3 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  width: 700px;
  margin-right: 160px;
  margin-left: 160px;
}


/* Curriculum-Div */

.Curriculum-Div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  color: red;
  font-size: 35px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10001;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.Curriculum-Titles {
  font-size: 45px;
}

.Sofiabordoni_Img {
  width: 400px;
}

#curriculum-column-1 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 20%;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

#curriculum-column-2 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 20%;
}

#curriculum-column-3 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 20%;
}

#curriculum-column-4 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 20%;
}

#curriculum-column-5 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 20%;
}


/* Media-queries */

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #main {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  #container_1 {
    justify-content: space-start;
  }
  #container_1>* {
    margin: 0rem;
    justify-content: space-start;
    margin-bottom: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 500px;
  }
  #contact {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 75%;
  }
  .Image {
    width: 400px;
  }
  /* Media-queries fo Slider  */
  .slider {
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .nav-bar-column-1 {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
  .nav-bar-column-2 {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
  .nav-bar-column-3 {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
  /* Media-queries fo curriculum */
  .Curriculum-Div {
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 650px;
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  .Sofiabordoni_Img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .Curriculum-Titles {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  #curriculum-column-1 {
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 90%;
  }
  #curriculum-column-2 {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 2px;
  }
  #curriculum-column-3 {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  #curriculum-column-4 {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  #curriculum-column-5 {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 2px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Sofia Bordoni</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>

<body>


  <div id="main">

    <div id="contact">
      Sofia Bordoni
      <br> sofiabordoni@gmail.com &nbsp;&nbsp; 0045&nbsp;9164&nbsp;6938 &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <span class="item item-1">
                     About
           </span>
    </div>



    <div id="container_1">

      <div class="item item-2" data-target="#text_2">
        <img class="Image" src="Images/310500_Normann_Copenhagen_Snooze_Bed_Linen_Deep_Sleep_White_Eclat_Cushion_33x60cm_Rose_Multi.jpg" width="300px">
      </div>

      <div class="item item-3" data-target="#text_3">
        <img class="Image" src="Images/Christmas Candle 20191-kopi kopi.png" width="400px">
      </div>

      <div class="item item-4" data-target="#text_4">
        <img class="Image" src="Images/Happy-New-Year-NC.gif" width="650px">
      </div>

      <div class="item item-5" data-target="#text_5">
        <img class="Image" src="Images/Normann-Anniversary-Cover_HomePage.jpg" width="450px">
      </div>

      <div class="item item-6" data-target="#text_6">
        <img class="Image" src="Images/Skærmbillede 2020-05-08 kl. 10.16.16 kopi.png" width="300px">
      </div>

      <div class="item item-7" data-target="#text_7">
        <img class="Image" src="Images/Tivoli.png" width="350px">
      </div>

      <div class="item item-8" data-target="#text_8">
        <img class="Image" src="Images/Ren.gif" width="600px">
      </div>

      <div class="item item-9" data-target="#text_9">
        <img class="Image" src="Images/6205_Normann_Copenhagen_Imprint_Towel_70x140cm_Group_01.jpg" width="350px">
      </div>

      <div class="item item-10" data-target="#text_10">
        <img class="Image" src="Images/330393_Normann_Copenhagen_Christmas_Candle_2018_Black_01.jpg" width="400px">
      </div>

      <div class="item item-11" data-target="#text_11">
        <img class="Image" src="Images/Holiday_Greeting_Main_NY.gif" width="650px">
      </div>

      <div class="item item-12" data-target="#text_12">
        <img class="Image" src="Images/Safari PSD Mockup_3.jpg" width="450px">
      </div>

      <div class="item item-13" data-target="#text_13">
        <img class="Image" src="Images/Asano Nielsen Design - Color Red.png" width="350px">
      </div>

      <div class="item item-14" data-target="#text_14">
        <img class="Image" src="Images/Papa-Blanket.gif" width="600px">
      </div>

      <div class="item item-15" data-target="#text_15">
        <img class="Image" src="Images/poster_mockup_MD1-kopi 3.jpg" width="350px">
      </div>

      <div class="item item-16" data-target="#text_16">
        <img class="Image" src="Images/Dizionari_DROGHERIA_CREATIVA_BAGLIONI.png" width="370px">
      </div>

      <div class="item item-17" data-target="#text_17">
        <img class="Image" src="Images/Skærmbillede 2020-05-07 kl. 19.17.28 kopi.png" width="380px">
      </div>

      <div class="item item-18" data-target="#text_18">
        <img class="Image" src="Images/Skærmbillede 2020-05-07 kl. 19.15.01 kopi.png" width="380px">
      </div>

      <div class="item item-19" data-target="#text_19">
        <img class="Image" src="Images/milano4you.png" width="450px">
      </div>

      <div class="item item-20" data-target="#text_20">
        <img class="Image" src="Images/Skærmbillede 2020-05-07 kl. 19.13.53 kopi.png" width="290px">
      </div>

      <div class="item item-21" data-target="#text_21">
        <img class="Image" src="Images/grido_leggero-kopi 3.jpg" width="420px">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slider">


    <div class="nav-bar-column-1">

      <div id="Menu">
        Menu:
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="nav-bar-column-2">


      <div id="text_2" class="hide_default" style="color: #26e08c">
        Category:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Textile design
           </em>
      </div>


      <div id="text_3" class="hide_default" style="color: #ff6699">
        Category:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Objects
           </em>
      </div>


      <div id="text_4" class="hide_default" style="color: #00cc66">
        Category:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Campaign
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_5" class="hide_default" style="color: #33cc33">
        Category:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Campaign
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_6" class="hide_default" style="color: #9966ff">
        Category:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Editorial design
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_7" class="hide_default" style="color:#e06726">
        Category:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Editorial design
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_8" class="hide_default" style="color: #3399ff">
        Category:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Textile design
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_9" class="hide_default" style="color: #00cc99">
        Category:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Textile design
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_10" class="hide_default" style="color: #ff9900">
        Category:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Object
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_11" class="hide_default" style="color: #3366ff">
        Category:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Campaign
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_12" class="hide_default" style="color:#5fe39f">
        Category:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Webdesign
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_13" class="hide_default" style="color: #056bfa">
        Category:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Campaign
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_14" class="hide_default" style="color: #e026b8">
        Category:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Textile design
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_15" class="hide_default" style="color: #e35f98">
        Category:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Campaign
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_16" class="hide_default" style="color: #32a852">
        Category:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Editorial design
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_17" class="hide_default" style="color: #4287f5">
        Category:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Branding
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_18" class="hide_default" style="color: #63f542">
        Category:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Editorial design
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_19" class="hide_default" style="color: #9942f5">
        Category:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Campaign
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_20" class="hide_default" style="color: #e02626">
        Category:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Editorial
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_21" class="hide_default" style="color: #e026b8">
        Category:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Campaign
            </em>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="nav-bar-column-3">

      <div id="text_2-2" class="hide_default" style="color: #26e08c">
        Project:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Bed Linen - Mood
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_3-2" class="hide_default" style="color: #ff6699">
        Project:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category"> 
            Christmas Candle 2019
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_4-2" class="hide_default" style="color: #00cc66">
        Project:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Christmas Campaign 2019.
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_5-2" class="hide_default" style="color: #33cc33">
        Project:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Anniversay Campaign.
            </em>
      </div>


      <div id="text_6-2" class="hide_default" style="color: #9966ff">
        Project:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            The Hyg Family Chair
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_7-2" class="hide_default" style="color:#e06726">
        Project:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Tivoli Catalogue
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_8-2" class="hide_default" style="color: #3399ff">
        Project:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            The Ren Collection
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_9-2" class="hide_default" style="color: #00cc99">
        Project:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Imprint Towel
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_10-2" class="hide_default" style="color: #ff9900">
        Project:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Christmas Candle 2019
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_11-2" class="hide_default" style="color: #3366ff">
        Project:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Christmas Campaign 2019
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_12-2" class="hide_default" style="color: #5fe39f">
        Project:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Beta Factory
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_13-2" class="hide_default" style="color: #056bfa">
        Project:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Asano Nielsen Design
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_14-2" class="hide_default" style="color: #e026b8">
        Project:
        <em class="color--category">
            Papa Blanket
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_15-2" class="hide_default" style="color: #e35f98">
        Project:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            CAFX
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_16-2" class="hide_default" style="color: #32a852">
        Project:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Hotel Baglioni.
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_17-2" class="hide_default" style="color: #4287f5">
        Project:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Hay Kitchen Market
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_18-2" class="hide_default" style="color: #63f542">
        Project:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Varier Collection 2017
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_19-2" class="hide_default" style="color: #9942f5">
        Project:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Milano 4 You
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_20-2" class="hide_default" style="color: #e02626">
        Project:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Book series cinque + uno
            </em>
      </div>

      <div id="text_21-2" class="hide_default" style="color: #e026b8">
        Project:&nbsp;
        <em class="color--category">
            Grido Leggero
            </em>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>


  <div class="Curriculum-Div" style="display: none;">



    <div id="curriculum-column-1">


      <img class="Sofiabordoni_Img" src="Images/Sofia.png">

      <br>
      <br> I love my childhood memories, which were filled with colors, papirs, pencils and handcraft works. I developed an obsession towards various kinds of creative fields: photography, developing analogue photos, architecture, - percieving buildings
      as shapes, volumes and combination of materials, as well as learning to look upon typography as shapes with entrenched characthers. When I realized that graphic design brought together all of these different passions of mine, I pursued it with enthusiasm.

    </div>

    <div id="curriculum-column-2">

      <em class="Curriculum-Titles">
            Education
           </em>
      <br>
      <br>
      <em>
            2013
           </em>
      <br> Scientific High School N. Tron Technology Plan
      <br>
      <br>
      <em>
            2016
           </em>
      <br> University Architecture of Venice IUAV Industrial Design and Multimedia
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>

      <em class="Curriculum-Titles">
            Interests
           </em>

      <br>
      <br> Graphic Design, Typography, Product Design, Textile, Accessories, Printing, Letterpress, Binding Architecture, Interior Design, Cultural Exhibitions, Art Photography
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>

      <em class="Curriculum-Titles">
            Collaborations
           </em>

      <br>
      <br>
      <em>
            BetaFactory / UnderBroen CPH
            </em>
      <br> Art direction / Graphic Designer <br> September 2017 – Present
      <br>
      <br>
      <em>
            Drogheria Creativa
            </em>
      <br> Art direction / Graphic Designer <br> January 2018 – January 2019 <br> Client: Baglioni Hotels <br>

    </div>

    <div id="curriculum-column-3">

      <em class="Curriculum-Titles">
             Experience
            </em>

      <br>
      <br>
      <em>
             Normann Copenhagen
             </em>
      <br> Graphic Product Designer<br> May 2018 - Present
      <br>
      <br>

      <em>
             Copenhagen Architecture Festival
             </em>
      <br> Graphic Product Designer <br> January 2018 - May 2018
      <br>
      <br>

      <em>
             Clara von Zweigberg Studio
             </em>
      <br> Graphic Designer Intern <br> Jan 2017 - July 2017 <br> Clients: HAY, Varier Furniture, Areaware
      <br>
      <br>
      <em>
             Studio FM Milano
             </em>
      <br> Graphic Designer Intern <br> Feb 2016 - July 2016 <br> Clients: Poltrona Frau, Cassina, Tecno
      <br>
      <br>
      <em>
             Studio Anagramma
             </em>
      <br> Graphic Designer Intern<br> June 2015 - Aug 2015
      <br>
      <br>
      <em>
             Università di Architettura Venezia IUAV
             </em>
      <br> Laboratory assistant <br> Feb 2015 - May 2015
      <br>
      <br>

    </div>


    <div id="curriculum-column-4">

      <em class="Curriculum-Titles">
             Competences
            </em>
      <br>
      <br>
      <em>
              Languages <br>
              </em> Italian (native), English (fluent), Danish (4th Module). <br>

      <br>
      <br>
      <em>
              Adobe Suite <br>
              </em> Indesign (expert), Illustrator (expert), Photoshop (expert), Lightroom (expert).

      <br>
      <br>
      <em>
              Operating systems <br>
              </em> Macintosh (expert), Windows (basic) <br>

      <br>
      <br>
      <em>
              Webprogramming <br>
              </em> HTML (basic), CSS (basic)

      <br>
      <br>
      <em>
              2D/3D modelling <br>
              </em> AutoCAD (basic), Rhinoceros (basic) <br>

    </div>

    <div id="curriculum-column-5">

      <em class="Curriculum-Titles">
             Workshop
             </em>
      <br>
      <br>
      <em>
              Form Us With Love / BAUX (Svezia) <br>
              </em> 16 June 2017
      <br>
      <br>

      <em>
              Touchpoint Design <br>
              </em> Left Loft / La Triennale di Milano <br> 12-13 Sept 2016
      <br>
      <br>

      <em>
              Welcome Design Workshop IUAV
              </em>
      <br> Studio FM Milano / Sergio Menichelli <br> September 2015
      <br>
      <br>
      <em>
              Schio Design Festival
              </em>
      <br> Graphic & Product Designer<br> Dec 2014 - Feb 2015
      <br>
      <br>
      <em>
              Workshop di Architettura Venezia IUAV
              </em>
      <br> Professors Paolo Merlini<br> July 2012
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>


  </div>



  </div>

  <script src="Onhover.js"></script>
  <script src="HoverColor.js"></script>
  <script src="Nav-Bar_expand.js"></script>
  <script src="MenuHide.js"></script>


  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vanilla-lazyload@13.0.1/dist/lazyload.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    const myLazyLoad = new LazyLoad({
      elements_selector: ".Image"
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of applying the CCS only on #contact element you could apply the jQuery selector on multiple elements like this:

```
$("#contact, div, span, .whateverClass").css('color', #colorYouWant);
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6n1zdycg/ like this? what the function of the id  #colorYouWant, in the end? should I add any additional let?

Comment: No additional let is require, you just have to enter the HEX value of the desired color. https://coolors.co/generate , for example #16425B is Indigo